# Looptool add-on circle option bad results

Tags: modeling, edges, topology

i was trting to circularize a face of an object by subdividing that single face but no matter what i do it's not giving me good results. i tried it by talking a new plane and subdividing it, it worked fine. but circularising a plane on that particcular object is giving me a shrinked circle and left twist of always 37 degrees. ofc i can manage it by rescaling that circle there are issues, you can't scale it to fit an exact radious and edges are messed up.

[image]

Comment: try to apply the scale, I guess your object has non uniform scale, so a circle looks distorted... be sure to be in Object Mode, press Ctrl+A and apply Scale at least... also check in the transformation panel how your scale changed to 1,1,1... btw, you can also use Mesh > Transform > To Sphere to get the circular shape

Comment: hey, sorry for the late reply. thanks that helped. i didnt think that could have been the issue. thanks!